# Call function from a file B in a loop in file A

Tags: python, loops

I have a python file B with all my function and a main code which is in loop of 0.25 sec, and I want to call this file in a loop in my file A. Can you get my weird mind ? 
What I did but only read the loop from file B once :

```
#FileA  
while 1:
    from FileB import *
```

And my file B :

```
#FileB
while t<0.25:
    #my stuff
```

Thanks.

PS : I forget to mention that i can't modify the file B.

Comment: why is your loop the main code if you want to call back on it multiple times? That is what a function is for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement only reads the target module one time.

If you have control of both files, I'd suggest that you make your loop a function in file B:

```
def main():
    while t<0.25:
        #my stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then you can call it repeatedly from file A:

```
from fileB import main as Bmain

while 1:
    Bmain()
```

If you don't have control of the source code for the files (meaning: if the code comes from someone else), there are a few options. Probably the easiest and fastest to code would be to use the [`os.system(command)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.system#os.system) function to run the contents of fileB in a separate process.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using `subprocess.call` (or one of the other tools in the `subprocess` module) instead of `os.system`. From the `os.system` docs (liked in the answer): "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Answer (score 0):

You should use [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), you don't have any functions in your questions. Here is an example:

```
# fileA.py
import time
from fileB import myFunction

def main():
    while True:
        ret = myFunciton()
        time.sleep(3)
main()

# fileB.py
def myFunction():
    print "running myFunction"
    return "result"
```